# Is Liquid Ocelot a brother to Liquid Snake?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-series

My understanding from a wiki is that Liquid Ocelot is a brother to Solid Snake, and Solid Snake is a brother of Liquid Snake. However, Liquid Snake isn't listed as a brother to Liquid Ocelot under 'Notable Family'.

Based on my understanding from the wiki, I would expect that they would be brothers through Solid Snake. Are they actually brothers?

https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Liquid_Ocelot

https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Liquid_Snake

https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Solid_Snake

Comment: This question can be answered through knowledge from the games, so I don't really see a problem here. It's likely OP got confused at the story (not surprising), looked up a wiki, and ended up even more confused.

Comment: @gecko - I've edited it to focus more on the relationships between the characters rather on whether the wiki is correct or not - I hope that's ok

Comment: That's actually perfect. Thank you

Comment: I'm not retracting my close vote; the question is unchanged, it is asking for clarification on a wiki, not a game.

Answer (score 1):

No, Liquid Ocelot and Liquid Snake are not brothers.

Liquid Ocelot is Liquid Snake's consciousness in Revolver Ocelot's body. Revolver Ocelot "hypnotized" himself to be Liquid Snake.

Liquid Ocelot's consciousness is brothers with Solid Snake, so that's why the wiki has it listed that way.

However, Liquid Snake isn't a brother to Liquid Ocelot because Liquid Snake's consciousness is part of Liquid Ocelot - As mentioned before, Liquid Ocelot is the mind of Liquid Snake in the body of Revolver Ocelot.